# Text area column size inconsistency in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, web, cross-browser, textarea

I have a text area which has 22 cols(columns/characters) and 16 rows defined.
But the **cols** allocated to the text area differs from browser to browser both in desktop and devices.

Following are some test results which i captured from testing a sample program (https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-snowflake-3ck5s).

### Platform: Windows

Google chrome, New Edge browser and Firefox seems to be allowing only 22 characters per a line.

### Platform: Mac

Safari and Google chrome always allows to enter 23 characters per a line.

### Platform: Android

Google chrome on Samsung J7 was allowing to enter only 22 characters per a line.
But Google chrome on Samsung S9 was allowing to enter 21 characters per a line.

But the output of following html was different than the above sample program. Where Google chrome and New Edge browser always only allows 21 characters per a line while Firefox was supporting 22.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Textarea Tests</title>

 <style>
  textarea {
   resize: none;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 Textarea 1:
 <textarea cols="22" rows="5">
 </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

So my conclusion is, There is no guarantee that we get exact cols we define in text areas.
It is always like **cols = n - 1** or **n + 1** on different browsers and devices.

Is there a javascript based solution to limit the number of cols in a row?

Answer (score 1):

The `cols` attribute doesn't state to be exact characters limit. But it states to an average of the specified value.

So, it is obvious to result in difference between browsers.

See it on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-cols):

> cols: The visible width of the text control, in average character widths.

You can use `wrap` to control it:

```
wrap="hard"
```

See how [wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-wrap) works:

> wrap: hard: The browser automatically inserts line breaks (CR+LF) so that each line has no more than the width of the control
>
> If this attribute is not specified, soft is its default value.

So, your html would be:

```
<textarea cols="22" rows="5" wrap="hard">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed default height and width for all devices

```
    textarea {
        width:264px;
        height:80px;
        resize: none;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```